# What is a word or phrase for something that, though you wouldn't have reasonably believed it to be real, actually turns out to be true?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

As an example:

> **Me:** "Did you hear about the congresswoman who believes in Jewish space lasers?"
> **You:** What are you even talking abo...oh my goodness; are you serious?!"

Comment: Are you suggesting that MTG's "Jewish space lasers"  starting  the CA fires will turn out to be true??

Comment: Not: `beggar belief​,` `incredibly,` `miracle,` `hardly believable,` `anything goes,` `curiouser and curiouser,` or, `There are more things in heaven and earth`

Comment: @Cascabel well it wasn't Billy Joel. He has an airtight alibi! -Stephen Colbert

Comment: What I meant was...the Q needs a little clarification.

Comment: @Cascabel Fair enough. I meant that her (or anyone else) SAYING it wouldn't have reasonably been considered to be an eventuality.

Comment: Why doesn't *unbelievable* work?

Comment: I think `unbelievable` answers the first half of the equation: "wouldn't reasonably believe it to be real" but the word I'm looking for addresses that it actually is no longer unbelievable when faced with the facts. You are no longer unbelieving though it may have STARTED as unbelievable.

Comment: @Kristopher Please [edit] the question to include all expansions and clarifications. (There are currently no answers to upset by changing it, and the question should stand on its own, without having to trawl through comments.) Thanks.

Comment: Strangely there were two answers...

Answer (score 0):

One relevant phrase is the saying that **"truth is stranger than fiction."** [Cambridge explains how this phrase is used:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/truth-is-stranger-than-fiction)

> said when you want to emphasize that real events or things are sometimes stranger than imaginary ones